# NiFi Registry docker file is not updating "Remote Clone Repository" property

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

NiFi Registry version 0.8.0 is not updating **Remote Clone Repository** in it's docker file. I am not sure whether it's a bug or there's some alternative. Any suggestions?

Here's the link for script file, [GitHub NiFi Registry Shell Script](https://github.com/apache/nifi-registry/blob/74c7435386b1118ed0b545efea7343deec6f4b29/nifi-registry-docker-maven/dockermaven/sh/update_flow_provider.sh)

Reported issue link [NiFi Registry JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFIREG-444)